# Install arm-poky-linux-gnueabi toolchain on PC

Tags: arm, toolchain

There are 2 compilers used in IMX7(ARM Yocto Linux):
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++

When I build complete image by spending about 2 hours its already downloaded.

But I would like to know how to install this tool chain directly on PC(Ubuntu/CentOS) and use it as separate compiler in PC instead of with its Image as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Use below command in your ubuntu pc

```
$ sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
$ sudo apt-get install g++-arm-linux-gnueabihf
```

Comment: Hi, following error occurs:                                                 [root@localhost ~]# yum install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.iphh.net
 * epel: ftp.cica.es
 * extras: centos.copahost.com
 * ius: archive.linux.duke.edu
 * updates: mirror.eu.oneandone.net
No package gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf available.
Error: Nothing to do

        and   Its same for g++

Comment: whats your os ubuntu or else